# Random number generation Function explanation

Tags: c++, random, casting, static, constants

Can anyone explain these two lines of function??

```
 int getRandomNumber(int min, int max)
 {
    static const double fraction = 1.0 / (RAND_MAX + 1.0);
    return min + static_cast<int>((max - min + 1) * (rand() * fraction));
 }
```

Comment: First explanation is that it is not C :-)

Comment: Please use the random number facilities in [`<random>`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/header/random) instead of `std::rand`. It has [`std::uniform_int_distribution`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/random/uniform_int_distribution) which does the same thing as this function, only better.

Comment: Please be more specific in your question. What exactly do you not understand?

Comment: `RAND_MAX + 1.0` has _implementation-defined_ results that can render code incorrect  when `RAND_MAX` does not convert exactly to a `double` and can be avoided.  When `RAND_MAX` is a [Mersenne Number](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/MersenneNumber.html), (this is very very common) `((RAND_MAX/2 + 1)*2.0)` is a good alternative.

Comment: `max - min` is prone to overflow,  `max - min + 1` may result in zero  - another weakness here.  `(1LLu + max - min)` is an alternative.

Comment: Code does not provide uniform distribution.  As @walnut suggests, do not use this code.  Bury it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like it's constraining [rand()](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/c_standard_library/c_function_rand.htm) function's output to fall inside a min and max.

a double type value `fraction` is calculated from `1.0 / (RAND_MAX + 1.0);`

RAND_MAX is a pre-compiler value defined in cstdlib or other header file or library, it's a big positive integer that represents the largest signed int your program can use. A higher RAND_MAX will make `fraction` lower since 1/number is a reciprocal; the reciprocal of 4 is 1/4 or 0.25. 5 is 1/5 or 0.20

The 1.0's are to implicitly cast RAND_MAX into a floating point number aka decimal; this makes sure that the / division / operator doesn't do integer division (5 / 2 == 2; vs 5.0 / 2.0 == 2.5)

```
return min + static_cast<int>((max - min + 1) * (rand() * fraction));
```

Return the integer representation of the min/max spread reduced by a random factor, added to the original minimum.
This line uses the min parameter value as a 'floor'. `static_cast<int>()` rounds down the floating point value of `((max - min + 1) * (rand() * fraction))` into an integer aka a whole number with no decimal parts. This cast is important for returning an int, but it also ensures that max is not exceeded by rounding down.

`(max - min + 1)` is the spread between the max and min parameters + 1. So if max == min you would be multiplying (rand() * fraction) by 1 instead of zero.

`rand()` generates a semi-random integer (no decimal parts) between 0 and RAND_MAX
Since `fraction` is the reciprocal of RAND_MAX + 1, fraction will always be < 1, and rand()s output will be a random portion of the min/max spread. The key part of understanding this function beyond the mixed C and C++ code confusion is knowing that RAND_MAX is used by the fraction variable AND the rand() function.
Think of the `(rand() * fraction)` part as a portion of distance from `min`

I would try feeding this function multiple values, tweaking the min, max, and fraction values each time and see how the output changes, you could probably find a pattern.
By making fraction smaller than (1.0 / RAND_MAX + 1.0) you can cluster the return values closer to the minimum.
(look up math ceiling and floor, and walnut's comment about uniform distribution). This can be done to smooth output, or make something more predictable, or cluster return values around an input value. If the math is the confusing part for you then messing around with code and seeing what happens will likely help your understanding and intuition of math functions.

Welcome to Stack Overflow!